# Type of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Anyone can give me a hint on how to solve $y(t)'=e^{-t}+y(t)^2$ with $y(0)=0$?

I've got to find out if this takes the Maximal interval of existence in $(T_{-}, T_{+})$ with $T_{+}< \infty$ or $T_{+}= \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Let's adress the second part. We have $y(t)'= e^{-t}+ y(t)^2 >0$, hence $y$ is strictly increasing. We set $T=T_+/2$ if $T_+<\infty$ or $T=1$ otherwise. Set $y_1= y(T)>0$ and

$$ x(t) = \frac{1}{\frac{2}{y_1}+T - t} $$

for $t\in [0, \frac{2}{y_1}+T)$. On checks that we have

$$ \begin{cases} x(t)' = x(t)^2 \\ x(T) = \frac{y_1}{2} \end{cases}.$$

We define

$$ T_0:= \inf \left\{ t \in \left[1, \frac{2}{y_1}+T \right) \  : \ y(t) > x(t) \right\}.$$

Assume that $T_0 < +\infty$. By continuity of both $x$ and $y$ we have $x(T_0)=y(T_0)$. However, we compute

$$ y(T_0) = y(T) + \int_T^{T_0} y(t)' dt = y(T) + \int_T^{T_0} e^{-t} + y(t)^2 dt  > x(T) + \int_T^{T_0} x(t)^2 dt = x(T) + \int_T^{T_0} x(t)' dt = x(T_0).$$

Hence, $T_0= +\infty$. This means $y(t) > x(t)$ for all $t \in \left[1, \frac{2}{y_1}+T \right)$. But $\lim_{t\uparrow \frac{2}{y_1}+T} x(t) = +\infty$, hence $$\lim_{t\uparrow \frac{2}{y_1}+T} y(t) = +\infty.$$

Thus, $T_+ < +\infty$.

Comment: Is it relevant to the problem because of $e^{-t}+y(t)^2\geq y(t)^2$, for t going to infinity?

Comment: Indeed. If the solution of $x'(t) = x(t)^2$ goes to plus infinity in finite time and you manage to show that the solution of your equation is larger than this function, then you're done.

Comment: @Thesinus I've given more details.

Answer (score 1):

To address your very first question:

---

If you want to solve for an exact and general solution, notice that this is a [Riccati Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).
$$y'=q_0(t)+q_1(t)y+q_2(t)y^2$$

Thus, if we substitute $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$, we can reduce this to a second-order linear ODE:

$$\left(-\frac{u'}{u}\right)'=e^{-t}+\left(-\frac{u'}{u}\right)^2$$
$$-\frac{u''}{u}+\left(-\frac{u'}{u}\right)^2=e^{-t}+\left(-\frac{u'}{u}\right)^2$$
$$u''+e^{-t}u=0$$
Unfortunately, the solution to this ODE contains [Bessel Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of the first and second kind:
$$u(t)=c_1 J_0\left(2\sqrt{e^{-t}}\right)+c_2 Y_0\left(2\sqrt{e^{-t}}\right)$$
This can be differentiated w.r.t. $t$ to obtain an explicit solution for $y(t)$ by substituting into $y(t)=-\frac{u'(t)}{u(t)}$.

---

Alternatively, if you want to avoid non-elementary functions, you can obtain a [series solution](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SeriesSolutions.aspx) to the original ODE.